# Asc Mav Framework can't find fcu_nodelet.launch

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to roslaunch the starmac package. I've made some modifications to the launch file but I get following error:

```
while processing /home/bob/ros/stacks/asctec_mav_framework/asctec_hl_interface/launch/fcu_nodelet.launch:
Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/home/bob/ros/stacks/asctec_mav_framework/asctec_hl_interface/launch/fcu_nodelet.launch
```

I took a peek for the file and it wasn't there any suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27474/asc-mav-framework-can%27t-find-fcu_nodelet.launch/) by [mrtc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1778/mrtc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 112 on 2012-02-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just noticed this here. Already answered on asctec-users list: [thread](http://asctec-users.986163.n3.nabble.com/fcu-nodelet-launch-missing-td3739271.html).

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) with karma: 2264 on 2012-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1